# Printing to PDF from Math StackExchange

Tags: support, export

I've tried the suggestions at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/printing-pages-from-m-s-e and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/is-it-possible-to-convert-and-possibly-download-the-answers-discussions-in-pdf, but printing to PDF distorts and removes the LATEX formatting. I do: File --> Print --> Select "Adobe PDF" as the printer. I've also tried StackPrinter but that didn't solve the problem.

May I please ask if anyone knows how to solve this problem?

I am using Firefox 19.0, Adobe Acrobat XI Pro (V11.0), and Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit version.

I'm trying to print [Proving Pascal's Rule : ${{n} \choose {r}}={{n-1} \choose {r-1}}+{{n-1} \choose r}$ when $1\leq r\leq n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose-r-when-1-leq) but the result is the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pScM.png
.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Perhaps duplicate of
[Is it possible to convert (and possibly download) the answers/discussions in pdf format?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/is-it-possible-to-convert-and-possibly-download-the-answers-discussions-in-pdf)

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thank you for your response. I should add that I also tried StackPrinter and that only gave me the same PDF, with the distortions and omissions of LATEX.

Comment: Yes. Printing from MSE "sucks the big one". Especially on MathJax heavy pages.

Comment: @LaPrevoyance This is what I get from StackPrinter: http://rapidshare.com/files/1068409794/TestMSE.pdf

Comment: What browser, version, operating system, PDF writer, etc. are you using?

Comment: Printing to PDF works fine for me (Firefox 19 with Mac OS X 10.8's built-in PDF output), so you can use this for the time being: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bdaw3690v8a6365/mse.pdf

Comment: I just checked with Firefox 19 on Linux and it worked fine too. Maybe it's just Windows, or "Adobe PDF", that doesn't like MathJax?

Comment: @RahulNarain: Thank you for your question and upload. I've updated my post with technical specifications. Martin Sleziak:  Thank you also for your upload.

Comment: @RahulNarain: The link is dead.